# Call window.showModalDialog after rendering of the page completes

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

I am using `window.showModalDialog` in my web application. When I click on a submit button I call this javascript from server side. Below is my code.

```
window.showModalDialog(URL, 'popUpWindow', 'dialogHeight:250px, dialogWidth:420px,scrollbars=No,toolbar=no,menubar=no,location=no,directories=no, status=yes, modal=yes');
```

Now the problem here is that when the modal popup comes my parent page i.e in background it shows me that page is still loading. I cant click on any other control except my `showModalDialog`. I want the background page to complete its activity and then open the dialog or else can we allow something like we can work on parent page while `showModalDialog` is on.?

Comment: Thats exactly for what a "modal" dialog is for.

Comment: So what can I do I my case.? Is there any other alternatives ?

Comment: You should use semicolons, not commas in the third argument.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the [`Document.readyState`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/readyState) for this. Maybe something like this:

```
if(document.readyState === "complete") {
    window.showModalDialog(URL, 'popUpWindow', 'dialogHeight:250px, dialogWidth:420px,scrollbars=No,toolbar=no,menubar=no,location=no,directories=no, status=yes, modal=yes');
}
```

The `readyState` of a document can be one of following:

**loading**

The document is still loading.

**interactive**

The document has finished loading and the document has been parsed but sub-resources such as images, stylesheets and frames are still loading. The state indicates that the `DOMContentLoaded` event has been fired.

**complete**

The document and all sub-resources have finished loading. The state indicates that the load event has been fired.

Or maybe add an event listener to the [readystatechange](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/readystatechange) event like this:

```
document.addEventListener("readystatechange", function(){
    if(document.readyState === "complete") {
        window.showModalDialog(URL, 'popUpWindow', 'dialogHeight:250px, dialogWidth:420px,scrollbars=No,toolbar=no,menubar=no,location=no,directories=no, status=yes, modal=yes');
    }

});
```

Comment: Hi Thanks Typo for your reply. I did it with jQuery using document.ready function. :)